# Git: Merge gives unexpected results

Tags: git, merge

I wasn't sure about the title on this one, feel free to edit if something is more suitable.

---

We were trying to do a big merge, and got unexpected results.

Here is the most minimal reproducible example I could come up with, sorry about it being long:

1. Create a new repo, with a single master branch
2. add a file to master, named `file1.txt`. Commit.
3. Create a new branch named `A` from the latest commit (created in 2).
4. Checkout `A`
5. Add 2 files: `bob.txt`, `alice.txt`
6. commit.
7. Now `A` has 3 files: `file1.txt`, `bob.txt`, `alice.txt`
8. Create a new branch `TARGET` from `master`'s HEAD. It has one file, `file1.txt` Eventually, we want this branch to have all 3 files.
9. Create branches for two developers, Alice and Bob, named `ALICE` and `BOB`, from `TARGET`'s HEAD that will serve them for merging changes made in A (and solve conflicts in their domain of the code base). Both branches have one file, `file1.txt`.
10. Bob's work: checkout `BOB`.
11. Merge `A` into `BOB`. Only take `bob.txt`, and leave `alice.txt`.
12. checkout `TARGET`
13. merge `BOB` into `TARGET`. commit. Now `TARGET` has 2 files: `file1.txt` and `bob.txt`
14. Alice's work: checkout `ALICE`
15. merge `A` into `ALICE`. Only take `alice.txt`, and leave `bob.txt`.
16. checkout `TARGET`
17. merge `ALICE` into `TARGET`. **`TARGET` only has 2 files: `file1.txt` and `bob.txt`. `alice.txt` remains in oblivion.**, which is not what I expected.

---

a. Why did 17. not give `alice.txt` to `TARGET`?

b. How should one go about merging by two different developers?

c. What is the best practice here that I am clearly missing?

Comment: On step 11: you can't leave `alice.txt`. When you merge `A` into `BOB` it's a fast-forward merge; there's no merge conflict; so you take all changes.

Comment: What does “only take” mean on step 11?

Comment: It isn't a fast forward merge. I am using a GUI which allows me

Comment: If you are using a GUI that runs `git merge --no-ff`, you should note that in the question itself. But, +1 (and question upvoted) for including a reproducer! See VonC's answer, which draws the resulting graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
 m--T-----Mb--Ma
 |       /    /
 |    --b    /
 |   /      /
 |--A      /
    \     /
     --a--
```

By the time 17 comes, `A` is already *indirectly* merged into `TARGET`, through Bob's branch (include `alice.txt` *deletion* from step 11).
Merging Alice's branch won't add any changes coming from `A` anymore, considering none of those files have changed.

> How should one go about merging by two different developers?

Alice should rebase her branch on top of `TARGET`, and ensure the target content is as expected, before merging back her branch to `TARGET`.

Comment: Ok maybe I don't understand.
I try this: 15) as in the question. 16) rebase on TARGET. I expected there to be 3 files on ALICE. Instead, `alice.txt` is not present, and `ALICE` and `TARGET` both point to the same commit containing only `bob.txt` and `file`.txt`

Comment: @Gulzar probably because Alice didn't make any change to any file.

Comment: So I still don't understand how should one go about a merge like this

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice here that I am clearly missing?

If `TARGET` has become the base branch for two separate branches `BOB` and `ALICE`, then Alice should rebase her branch against `TARGET` as soon as Bob merges his in `TARGET`.

⚠️ Don't rebase `TARGET` against any other branches until both Bob and Alice branches are merged in `TARGET`; it will cause unnecessary conflicts. If you need to update `TARGET` while people are still working, do a merge instead.

Comment: Ok maybe I don't understand. I try this: 15) as in the question. 16) rebase on TARGET. I expected there to be 3 files on ALICE. Instead, alice.txt is not present, and ALICE and TARGET both point to the same commit containing only bob.txt and file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it myself. Following your instructions, you end up with **neither bob.txt nor alice.txt**. The explanation is that when you merge on steps 11 and 15, you are deleting both files (each file on each merge) and so when you end up merging *both* branches, both files will end up in oblivion.... I don't know what you did to get bob.txt to show up there at all. Here's my script, feel free to make any comments:

```
echo step 1
git init ./

echo step 2
touch file1.txt
git add file1.txt
git commit -m "file1.txt" file1.txt

echo step 3
git branch A

echo step 4
git checkout A

echo step 5
touch bob.txt
touch alice.txt

echo step 6
git add bob.txt alice.txt
git commit -m "alice.txt and bob.txt" alice.txt bob.txt

echo step 7 is just check that A has all 3 files
if [ ! -f alice.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file alice.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f bob.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file bob.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f file1.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file1.txt
    exit 1
fi

echo step 8
git branch TARGET master

echo step 9
git branch ALICE TARGET
git branch BOB TARGET

echo step 10
git checkout BOB

echo step 11
git merge --no-ff --no-commit A
# we now have all files... again
if [ ! -f alice.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file alice.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f bob.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file bob.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f file1.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file1.txt
    exit 1
fi
# we remove alice.txt
git rm -f alice.txt
git commit -m "Merging A into BOB, remove alice.txt"

echo step 12
git checkout TARGET

echo step 13
git merge BOB --no-commit --no-ff
if [ -f alice.txt ]; then
    echo Was NOT expecting to find file alice.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f bob.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file bob.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f file1.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file1.txt
    exit 1
fi
git commit -m "Merging BOB into TARGET".

echo step 14
git checkout ALICE

echo step 15
git merge --no-ff --no-commit A
# now we have again all 3 files
if [ ! -f alice.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file alice.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f bob.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file bob.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f file1.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file1.txt
    exit 1
fi
# remove bob.txt
git rm -f bob.txt
git commit -m "Merging A into ALICE, remove bob.txt"

echo step 16
git checkout TARGET

echo step 17
git merge --no-commit --no-ff ALICE
# at this point, we should NOT have either alice.txt or bob.txt
if [ -f alice.txt ]; then
    echo Was NOT expecting to find file alice.txt
    exit 1
elif [ -f bob.txt ]; then
    echo Was NOT expecting to find file bob.txt
    exit 1
elif [ ! -f file1.txt ]; then
    echo Was expecting to find file1.txt
    exit 1
fi
git commit -m "Merging ALICE into TARGET"
```

Run it inside a newly created directory (don't even run `git init` on it. The script will take care of it).

Original Answer

On step 11, when you say *leave alice.txt*, you mean you are not carrying it over? Then in this branch you are *deleting* alice.txt.

Same concept on step 15. You are *deleting* bob.txt.

My question would be *why do you have bob.txt if it is being deleted on ALICE? But it's probably because I'm mentally following history so I must have skipped something.... but alice.txt? You are deleting it on step 11.

Comment: I guess it is confusing. Yes, "leaving" actually is Deleting, i didn't notice that when asking the question (or when thinking about it). It does make sense twice, because it happens on private branches.

Comment: So you got it? I'm not sure from your comment

Comment: I deleted it, yes.

Comment: why `git rm -f bob.txt` and not just `rm -f bob.txt`? same for alice. I didn't remove any file from git history at any phase. I only made changes to the file system and committed them.

Comment: Ok... let me ask: what do you mean with 'take some-file, leave other-file'?

Comment: I mean after `git merge --no-ff --no-commit A`, `reset` the file I "don't take", and `add`, and `commit` the other one.

Comment: Thrn you are taking both files because both are already added when `git merge --no-commit` runs.